# Pass multiple parameters to controller from route in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have in

routes:

```
Route::get('feed/{type?}/{first?}/{second?}/{third?}', ['as' => 'feed', 'uses' => 'PostController@feed']);
```

controller:

```
public function feed(Request $request, $type, $first, $second, $third)
{
...
```

But this produce error:

```
ErrorException in PostController.php line 209:
Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Controllers\PostController::feed()
```

What I am doing bad? What I forgot?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters)

> Make sure to give the route's corresponding variable a default value

So it should be like this:

```
public function feed(Request $request = null, $type = null, $first = null, $second = null, $third = null)
{
...
```

You can replace `null` with default value of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the arguments as optional too like

```
public function feed(Request $request, $type = '', $first = '', $second = '', $third = '')
{
```